# Wie sagt man "Do you know if something?" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

Wie kann man sagen z.B. "Do you know if there's a bar in Munich?" auf Deutsch? Oder "Do you know if we have a midterm exam tomorrow?"

Comment: Did you try to translate it yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Weißt du, ob ...?
```

Dafür deine Beispiele:

```
Weißt du, ob es in München eine Bar gibt?
```

Oder

```
Weißt du, ob wir morgen eine Prüfung (Zwischenprüfung) haben?
```

Comment: Oder "Wissen Sie, ob ...?", je nachdem, ob man den Angesprochenen duzt oder siezt.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sound casual you could add words like 'zufälligerweise', 'nicht etwa' or 'vielleicht' in the translation.

> - Weißt du/Wissen Sie *zufälligerweise*, ob es...?
> - Du weißt/Sie wissen doch *nicht etwa*, ob es...?
> - Hast du 'ne Ahnung/Haben Sie eine Ahnung, ob es *vielleicht*...?

So my suggested versions above would include a *by any chance* as in "Do you know *by any chance*..."

For a more neutral question, I would suggest:

> - Weißt du/Wissen Sie, ob...?